# How to remove crosshair and outline in wafer-map generated image?

Tags: python

I am trying to create wafer maps using Python.

I have tried the package [wafer-map 1.1.2](https://pypi.org/project/wafer-map/) using this code:

```
from wafer_map import wm_app
data = [(x_coordinate1, y_coordinate1, SBIN value),(x_coordinate1, 
       y_coordinate1, SBIN value),...]
wm_app.WaferMapApp(data,(9.402,7.482),(19.5,15.5),300,edge_excl=0, 
flat_excl=0)
```

I am getting the following output:

[image]

But I would like to have an output like this:

[image]

From the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/wafer-map/#keyboard-shortcuts-and-mouse-usage) I learned that there are keyboard shortcuts for removing this wafer outline and crosshair in the interactive viewer:

> - **O**
>
>   - Toggle display of wafer and exclusion outline
> - **C**
>
>   - Toggle crosshair display

But I would like to do it programmatically.

What do I have to write in my script to remove the wafer outline and crosshair and save the image to a file?

Comment: Yes tried, but it is manual, i am trying to create the wafer maps with out grid, legend, wafer_outline and crosshairs, then save it to a file. I manage to disable the legend and grid, but i couldn't disable wafer_outline and crosshairs.